# Script to disable/enable PnP Device using InstanceID's - but the ID's change upon reboot

Tags: windows-10, powershell, array

I have a working script to disable 4 usb joysticks using their respective InstanceID's

```
$pnpIds = 'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&1699A0E&198&0000', 'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&5438EB5&19D&0000', 'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&390C5738&17D&0000','HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&2652A693&16C&0000'

foreach ($pnpId in $pnpids) 
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $pnpId -Confirm:$false
}
```

It works fine when executing, problem is upon reboot the ID's change.. only 3 characters change at the end in between the "&" characters (HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&1699A0E&**198**&0000 The rest remains the same. Anyway to use wildcards for those 3 characters? It uses letters and numbers.

If not is there a way to write a script that will fetch the current InstanceID's for the USB joysticks then disable/enable them with the script I currently am using? Way out of my league here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can! The best place to start is with just `Get-PnpDevice`, to **make sure** that you're only selecting the devices you expect to:

```sh
# use * as a wildcard
Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId 'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&1699A0E&*&0000'

# example output on my PC:
Status     Class           FriendlyName            InstanceId     
------     -----           ------------            ----------     
OK         Keyboard        HID Keyboard Device     HID\VID_0079...
OK         Mouse           HID-compliant mouse     HID\VID_0079...
```

Then you can use basically the same script (I'm guessing on where the wildcard goes):

```
$pnpIds = 
  'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&1699A0E&*&0000',
  'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&5438EB5&*&0000',
  'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&390C5738&*&0000',
  'HID\VID_0079&PID_0006\7&2652A693&*&0000'

foreach ($pnpId in $pnpids) {
  Get-PnpDevice -InstanceID $pnpId | 
    Where Status -Like 'OK' |
      Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
}
```

You cannot use a wildcard in `Disable-PnpDevice`, but it **will** disable any device(s) piped to it, including lists of multiple devices, so be careful that you don't disable anything accidentally.

`Get-PnpDevice` can also use a wildcard for searching by `-FriendlyName` or `-Class` if that's easier.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestions. The wildcards are inserted at the correct spots. However I get the following error -

Comment: At line:1 char:28
+ foreach ($pnpId in $pnpids)
+                            ~
Missing statement body in foreach loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingForeachStatement

Comment: Also when listing devices via Get-PnpDevice for each game controller, 2 entries come back. Status shows OK for one and Unknown for the other. I pulled the InstanceID from the OK status and confirmed it works. The unknown InstanceID is the same except for the 'wildcard' characters there are only 2 (&7F&) Whereas the working one has 3 (&1A0&). The 'unknown' ID gives an error when trying to disable. Maybe this is an issue?

Comment: whoops, I had missed an `{`, fixed in the answer. I've also added a `Where` clause to only try and disable devices that are `OK`. I don't know what the other unknown devices might be - lots of software interacts with controllers like the 'USB Game Controllers' settings, xbox drivers, Steam controller mappings/assignments, etc. Maybe one of those is creating virtual devices?

Comment: Think its almost there, here is the error I am getting

Comment: Disable-PnpDevice : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does
not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:4 char

Comment: At line:4 char:7
+       Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $pnpId -Confirm:$false
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Win32_PnPEntity...A0E&1A0&000...):PSObject) [Disable-PnpDevice], Param
   eterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Disable-PnpDevice

Comment: Too much copying and pasting from me - I've removed the `-InstanceId $pnpId` on `Disable-PnpDevice` and it should play nice now

Comment: Perfect.. nicely done, thankyou!
To Enable I had to add  - Where Status -Like 'Error'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DevCon utility[1] from Microsoft? It supports wildcards

`devcon.exe find "USB\VID_3495&PID_00E0*"`

USB\VID_3495&PID_00E0\123456789                             : USB Debug Connection Device
1 matching device(s) found.

it supports many commands like Disable/Enable.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon